# how to set a field to the current date

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

A user logs in and then the current date should be inplanted in the field 'LastActivity'.

With this date I can make a query that shows me all the logged in users.

How do I do this?
Can anybody help me please?

Comment: You'd probably want to add your language of choice and database format to the tags. Is this PHP and MySQL? Are we talking about Microsoft Access? Or how about dBase?

Comment: Where do u want to use it ,

Comment: What language? What have you tried?

Comment: Stupid, I forgot to tell it is PHP and MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
update myTable set myField = now();
```

Best is to make sure the table column is set to type Date. Otherwise you will also get the time with it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of updating by hand, you can define your column as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE foo(
   lastActivity TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

You will not only get the date with this one, but also the time. In your query you can then use

```
SELECT DATE(lastActivity) ...
```

to only get the date part.

Answer (score -1):

Don't forget to add a field to store the date/time of user logout.
Otherwise you only know which users have ever logged in, instead of current sessions.
;-)